# Android Room: Include Nested Object's Fields as Columns

Tags: android, entity-relationship, android-room

Let's say I have a `Patient` entity, storing the patient ID, a boolean and finally a `Person` object. So I annotate these fields with `@ColumnInfo` to store in the database.

Now a `Person` has 2 String fields: a first name and last name.

However, in my `patients` table, I want to have a column directly for the first name and last name fields (from `Person`), and so I want to be able to call e.g. `firstName` (and not having to call `Person.firstName`) from a query. How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use **@Embedded** annotation of Room for it.

In your case it will be as follows

```
   public class Person {
       String firstName;
       String lastName;
   }

   public class Patient {
       int patientId;//just an assumption
       @Embedded
       Person person;
   }
```

For more information check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Embedded)
**Note :** I haven't provided other annotations like **@ColumnInfo** for brevity

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to ask, does this also apply to objects defined inside the Embedded object? (e.g. `Person` has a `PersonAddress` object)

Comment: Yes. Room permits nested embedded objects

Comment: Can you make an example with full DAO, Client?